# How to add make the scrollpane work?

Tags: java, jtable, jframe, jscrollpane

I have a form here that I made, and I have been trying to add the Global.table1 to a scrollpane when adding it to the Global.uniConPane which is my contentpane. With this current code it only show the table without the column names. When i try to add these code below:

```
      Global.uniConPane.add(new JScrollPane(Global.table1));
```

It doesnt display anything. These set of codes' purpose is to add a new row when a new item is being sold. I want to be able to add the scrollpane but i cant make it work.

```
      private static void addSalesForm() throws IOException {
      Global.UniFrameTitle = "Clinic Inventory Manager";
      Global.uniConPane.setOpaque(true);
      Global.uniConPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      Global.uniConPane.setLayout(null);   
      Global.chosen="no";

      headerFunction();
      loggedIn();
      menuFunction();
      Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Select Product");
      Border border1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
      Global.superGroup.setBorder(border);
      Global.superGroup.setSize(740,80);
      Global.superGroup.setLocation(20,92);


      Global.model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
      Global.model1.addColumn("Product Name");
      Global.model1.addColumn("Price");
      Global.model1.addColumn("Quantity");
      Global.model1.addColumn("Subtotal");
      Global.table1 = new JTable(Global.model1);

      Global.table1.setSize(490,350);
      Global.table1.setLocation(22,190);
      Global.table1.setBorder(border1);
      JLabel pro = new JLabel("<html><font color='black'>Product Name<br /></font></html>");
      pro.setSize(200,15);
      pro.setLocation(50,117); 
      JLabel pri = new JLabel("<html><font color='black'>Price<br /></font></html>");
      pri.setSize(200,15);
      pri.setLocation(265,117); 
      JLabel sto = new JLabel("<html><font color='black'>Item On Hand<br /></font></html>");
      sto.setSize(200,15);
      sto.setLocation(385,117); 
      JLabel count = new JLabel("<html><font color='black'>Quantity<br /></font></html>");
      count.setSize(200,15);
      count.setLocation(505,117); 
    itemDropDownList();
    Global.itemList.setEditable(true);
    Global.itemList.setSize(200, 20);
    Global.itemList.setLocation(50,135);
    JButton addProduct = new JButton("Add Item");
    addProduct.setSize(100,20);
    addProduct.setLocation(621,135);
    new clinicInventorySystem2(Global.itemList);
        Global.unitPrice = new JTextField();
        Global.unitPrice.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        Global.unitPrice.setSize(100,20);Global.unitPrice.setLocation(265,135);
        Global.unitPrice.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        Global.quantity = new JTextField();
        Global.quantity.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        Global.quantity.setSize(100,20);Global.quantity.setLocation(385,135);
        Global.quantity.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        Global.quan = new JTextField();
        Global.quan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        Global.quan.setSize(100,20);Global.quan.setLocation(505,135);
        Global.quan.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        Global.uniConPane.add(Global.unitPrice);
        Global.uniConPane.add(Global.quantity);
        Global.uniConPane.add(Global.quan);
        Global.uniConPane.add(pro);
        Global.uniConPane.add(pri);
        Global.uniConPane.add(sto);
        Global.uniConPane.add(count);
    Global.uniConPane.add(addProduct);
    Global.uniConPane.add(Global.superGroup);
    Global.uniConPane.add(Global.itemList);
    Global.uniConPane.add(Global.table1);

    addProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Global.t2 = Integer.parseInt(Global.quan.getText());
            Global.subt = Global.t1 * Global.t2;
            String temp = ""+Global.subt;
        String[] itemize = { Global.valueItem, Global.unitPrice.getText(), Global.quan.getText(),temp };
        Global.model1.addRow(itemize);
      }
    });
    Global.itemList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            Global.valueItem = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            Global.chosen = "yes";
            Global.valueItemPass = Global.valueItem;
            System.out.println(Global.valueItem);
          try
            {
              Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
              Global.database = 
                 "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\\floresClinic.accdb;";
              Global.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Global.database, "", "");
              Global.s = Global.conn.createStatement();

             Global.rs = Global.s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM medItem WHERE productID = '" + Global.valueItem+"' ");
             int cou = 0;
             Integer tempVar=0;
                while(Global.rs.next())
                {
                    tempVar=Integer.parseInt(Global.rs.getString("itemID"));
                    String s1 = Global.rs.getString("unitPrice");
                    Global.t1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
                    Global.unitPrice.setText(s1);
                    Global.unitPrice.setEditable(false);
                        cou++;
                }  
                 Global.rs = Global.s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM medInventory WHERE itemID = " + tempVar);
                 cou = 0;
                    while(Global.rs.next())
                    {
                        Global.quantity.setText(Global.rs.getString("qty"));
                        Global.quantity.setEditable(false);
                            cou++;
                    }               
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Global.uniConPane.add(Global.logLabel);
    Global.uniConPane.add(Global.bg);
    Global.uniFrame.setJMenuBar(Global.menuBar);
    Global.uniFrame.setTitle(Global.UniFrameTitle);
    Global.uniFrame.setSize(800, 650);
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - Global.uniFrame.getWidth()) / 2);
    int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - Global.uniFrame.getHeight()) / 2);
    Global.uniFrame.setLocation(x, y-10);
    Global.uniFrame.setContentPane(Global.uniConPane);
    Global.uniFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Global.uniFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

I am really sorry if my code is a bit hard to understand. But I hope someone can help me make the scrollpane work.

Comment: Try creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Get rid of `Global.uniConPane.add(Global.table1);` and replace it with `Global.uniConPane.add(new JScrollPane(Global.table1));`.  It looks like you're using `static` references, this is an incredibly bad idea, especially within a GUI environment, where you might be required to have multiple instances of a component show at the same time.

Comment: @MadProgrammer when i changed it to your advise the table is not visible. no errors are being prompted but it doesn't show the table.

Comment: That's because it's a symptom of a larger problem.  Refrain from using `null` layouts. You do not control the factors that affect the size requirements/decisions for components that will change their sizes on different platforms/os's